# I am doing a gas station project in python, there is an error

Tags: python

```
print ("Welcome to the Gas Station!")
infiniteLoop = True
total = 0  
while True and infiniteLoop :
   
   print ("\n Gasoline \n Market \n Restaurant \nTotal \n quit to exit")
   select = input("Select One:")
   
   if select == "Gasoline":
       select1 = input("92 - 1 manat \n95 - 1.40 manat \n Diesel - 0.90 cents \n Premium - 2 manat \nWhat Gasoline Do You Want:")
       l = int(input("type liter:"))
       if select1 == "92":
           a = l * 1
           total = total + a
           print(a, "Manat")
           print("Gasoline Injected.")
       elif select1 == "95":
            b = l * 1.40
            total+= b   # update total amount
            b = print(b, "Manat")
            print("Gasoline Injected.")

       elif select1 == "Diesel": # Diesel needs to be String "Diesel"
            c = l * 1.90 
            total = total + c  # update total
            print(c, "Manat")
            print("Gasoline Injected.")
       elif select1 == "Premium": # Premium needs to be sting, in your code has no quote
            d = l * 2.0
            total = total + d
            print(d, "Manat")
            print("Gasoline Injected.")
            
   elif select == "Total":
        print("Total Amount:", total)
    # terminate infinite loop 
   elif select == 'quit':
       infiniteLoop = False
```

I'm new to Python, I'm doing a gas station project, I haven't finished it yet, when I select a total in the code it says there is no "a" element, can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Please read about [how to ask good quesitons](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so the community can better serve you.

Comment: Your issue is that you are assigning your variables `a`, `b`, etc. in the if statements, so they only "exist" if that if statement is `True`.

Comment: Instead of `a = `, `b =` and so on, you should just do `a = ` for all of them and at the end `print ("Total Amount:", a)`

Comment: Post the full traceback so that we see the extact text of the error and the failing line. I assume this was a NameError?

Comment: You should also read about the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function, as it does not return a value so all your variables will evalute to `None`.

Answer (score 1):

two problems

- not all `if-elif` branches are guaranteed to have happened before "total", so, some variables might not exist when you try to print `a+b+c+d`
- You assign to `a, b, c, d` the result of calling `print(...)`, which is `None`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the following, your variables, a, b, c and d are declared in your if / elif statement. Which means their scope is inside those statement.

What's a scope ? It's the "area" of code where your variables will be recognized as "existing".

For example :

```
def foo(a) :
    if a is true :
        b = "bar"
    print(b)
```

In this case, the scope of `b` is within the if statement, everything after this assignation in the if will have access to it. So, at the moment of the `print(b)` call, b is unknown, because we are outside of the scope.

So, to fix your problem, you should define your variables outside of your ifs. Like this :

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
if(#####)
    if select1 == 92:
        a = print(l * 1, "Manat")
        print("Gasoline Injected.")
    elif select1 == 95:
        b = print(l * 1.40, "Manat")
        print("Gasoline Injected.")
    elif select1 == Diesel:
        c = print(l * 0.90, "Manat")
        print("Gasoline Injected.")
    elif select1 == Premium:
        d = print(l * 2.0, "Manat")
        print("Gasoline Injected.")
if select == "Total":
    print("Total Amount:", a + b + c + d)
```

Second point, the return value of the `print` function in python is `None`, which means you are assigning `None` to your variables a, b, c, d.

So, to correct your a, b, c, d, you should do :

```
a = l * 1
b = l * 1.40
c = l * 0.90
d = l * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

### Small issues in your code

---

a. String "Diesel" not equal to Diesel

b. Indentation

c. Variable scopes, etc

Anyway, here's a working code, run it and check what's wrong with your code.

```
print ("Welcome to the Gas Station!")
infiniteLoop = True
total = 0  
while True and infiniteLoop :
   
   print ("\n Gasoline \n Market \n Restaurant \nTotal \n quit to exit")
   select = input("Select One:")
   
   if select == "Gasoline":
       select1 = input("92 - 1 manat \n95 - 1.40 manat \n Diesel - 0.90 cents \n Premium - 2 manat \nWhat Gasoline Do You Want:")
       l = int(input("type liter:"))
       if select1 == "92":
           a = l * 1
           total = total + a
           print(a, "Manat")
           print("Gasoline Injected.")
       elif select1 == "95":
            b = l * 1.40
            total+= b   # update total amount
            b = print(b, "Manat")
            print("Gasoline Injected.")

       elif select1 == "Diesel": # Diesel needs to be String "Diesel"
            c = l * 1.90 
            total = total + c  # update total
            print(c, "Manat")
            print("Gasoline Injected.")
       elif select1 == "Premium": # Premium needs to be sting, in your code has no quote
            d = l * 2.0
            total = total + d
            print(d, "Manat")
            print("Gasoline Injected.")
            
   elif select == "Total":
        print("Total Amount:", total)
    # terminate infinite loop 
   elif select == 'quit':
       infiniteLoop = False
```